# Add robots.txt for Laravel 9+

Tags: laravel, robots.txt

I want to add robots.txt to my Laravel project but robots.txt packages I found are not compatible with Laravel 9+ so if you know there is any tutorial or package for latest version of Laravel, please share. Thanks.

Comment: Why do you need a specific package for robots.txt, it's just a text file. Do you need to generate it dynamically?

Comment: wow, I don't know about it. I want Google to crawl my website instead of any restricted pages like admin.

Answer (score 0):

To add a robots.txt file for a Laravel 9+ application, follow these steps:

- Create a new file named robots.txt in the public directory of your Laravel project. You can use any text editor to create this file.
- Open the `robots.txt` file and add the following lines:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /admin
```

Comment: Great thanks a lot. I will do it right away. How do I stop Google from crawling client account pages?

Comment: User-agent: *
Disallow: /admin
Disallow: /client

How about this?

Answer (score 0):

Use the URL in your Routes files (web.php ++) as reference. Work through each route, adding each `/names-of-different-areas-in-my-site/..` listing each route/directory you know to contain files that shouldn't be crawled, in your robots.txt file under a Disallow: block/column/array (verbose terminology here, because *each to their own* and it's anyones guess how you wanna term them)